# Is this a problem that has already been solved?

Tags: problem-solving, decision-theory

I have a question paper with $n$ True/False questions and I don't know the answer to any of those questions. My objective is to find the answer key of the question paper. All I have is a machine which will tell my total score out of $n$, when I submit my answer sheet(I must mark either T/F for all the questions). What strategy should I follow to ensure that I find the answer key in minimum number of submissions?

Is the above problem already known and solved?

PS: I am not really sure about the tags. Please edit them if they are wrong.

Comment: Is there a particular distribution of the answers? Or should we just assume that its uniform?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I don't see why we need to assume a distribution.

Comment: Isn't that required to get performance analysis? Similar to average case vs worst case for sorting algorithms. Intuitively I'd guess that a binary-style of testing that recursively split the questions into two groups would outperform the basic strategy of changing one answer at a time, but only if the answers were not uniformly distributed between true and false.

Comment: Ok, let's assume it's uniform.

Comment: I suspect in general that this problem parallels that of sorting with repeated values, namely a string of $0$'s and $1$'s. Not sure though; just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this has already been solved.

Think of this problem as a simple version of the MasterMind (code-breaker) game. In this simple version there are only 2 colors, black and white (true and false).

The maximum number of tries is $$ \lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor +2$$

You can find the proof [here](http://snovit.math.umu.se/Personal/jaeger_gerold/publ/mastermind.pdf) in chapter 4.

Comment: Thank you!. For some reason I thought the answer might be in log scale.